# Read lines without regexp?

Tags: c++, c

How read such lines in C++, without using regexp:

```
name(numeric_value_or_some_string[, numeric_value_or_some_string]) [name(numeric_value_or_some_string[, numeric_value_or_some_string])]
```

for example:

```
 VM(4, 2) VR(7) VP(8, 3) I(VIN)
```

**I am curries how to easily check if the string is in valid form.**

Comment: You could read characters one by one and decide if is well formed.

Comment: Try to think about what you expect to get next at any point in the input as you loop through it. You should be able to check the validity of such a string in one pass.

Comment: what's the exact goal? efficiency for something less expressive than regular expressions? no regexes as an exercise? Apart form that I have a hard time matching your description with your example. Especially the commata are confusing

Comment: I also add my cents to knowing what your aim is. Improve efficiency by eliminating regexp or learning. Anyway, breaking up the input and parsing it is not a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just plain string parsing, no magic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  std::string str = "VM(4, 2) VR(7) VP(8, 3) I(VIN)";
  std::string name;
  size_t pos = 0;
  while(pos < str.size()){
    if(str.at(pos) == '('){
      ++pos;
      std::vector<std::string> values;
      std::string currentValue;
      while(pos < str.size()){
        if(str.at(pos) == ')'){
          if(!currentValue.empty()){
            values.push_back(currentValue);
            currentValue.clear();
          }
          break;
        }else if(str.at(pos) == ','){
          if(!currentValue.empty()){
            values.push_back(currentValue);
            currentValue.clear();
          }
        }else if(str.at(pos) == ' '){
          /* intentionally left blank */
          /* ignore whitespaces */
        }else{
          currentValue.push_back(str.at(pos));
        }
        pos++;
      }
      std::cout << "-----------" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
      for(size_t i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
        std::cout << "Value "<< i <<": " << values.at(i) << std::endl;
      }
      std::cout << "-----------" << std::endl;
      name.clear();
    }else if(str.at(pos) == ' '){
          /* intentionally left blank */
          /* ignore whitespaces */
    }else{
      name.push_back(str.at(pos));
    }
    ++pos;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output for your sample:

```
-----------
Name: VM
Value 0: 4
Value 1: 2
-----------
-----------
Name: VR
Value 0: 7
-----------
-----------
Name: VP
Value 0: 8
Value 1: 3
-----------
-----------
Name: I
Value 0: VIN
-----------
```